# Call to a member function canBeViewed() on string

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a fix I am having where my users are able to change the URL and view data other than that users own data. I created a couple of function but am getting this error on my dashboardcontroller.php. Any ideas?

`dashboard.php`

```php
if (!$call_center->canBeViewed(Auth::user())) {
    return abort(403, 'Forbidden');
}
```

`user.php`

```php
public function hasPermission($role_id): boolean
{
    $role_id = $this->roles()->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->firstOrFail();

    if ($role_id['id'] == '2' || $role_id['id'] == '3' || $role_id['id'] == '4') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`Callcenter.php`

```php
public function canBeViewed(User $user) : boolean
{
    if ($user->hasPermission('canViewAllCenters') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `$call_center` is a string instead of User object. `var_dump($call_center)` or `Log::info($call_center)` and check the Laravel logs to find out what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `$call_center` is an **INSTANCE** of `CallCenter` class instead of just the class name

```php
$call_center = new CallCenter(); // Initialize the instance
if (!$call_center->canBeViewed(Auth::user())) {
    return abort(403, 'Forbidden');
}
```

The above example will most likely not work

My best guess is that `$call_center` is a `Model`

So in your `DashboardController.php` file, find where `$call_center` is queried and make sure you're not assigning it to an attribute instead of the object

## Hypothetical Code based on my Psychic skillz

Change your code from something like this

```php
$call_center = CallCenter::where('location', 'Mumbai')->first()->name;
```

To something like this

```php
$call_center = CallCenter::where('location', 'Mumbai')->first();
```